# how to display all the users in table users to my subjects table in add.ctp view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here is my subjects add.ctp view

```
<?= $this->Form->create($subject) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Subject') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('math');
        echo $this->Form->input('english');
        echo $this->Form->input('history');
        echo $this->Form->input('science');

       ******this field will display all the users in drop down************* from users table
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

****UsersController.php ****

```
public function index()
{


     $user=  $this->set('users', $this->paginate());

    $this->set('user', $user);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);


}
```

How to achieve this one please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want user select box(Dropdown) in the subject add.ctp then you should send all the list of user from add() of SubjectsController.

In subjects add method

```
public function add()
{
    //Your previous logics      

    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $users=  $this->Users->find('list');

    $this->set('users', $users);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    //Your previous logics
}
```

In your subject add.ctp

```
<?= $this->Form->create($subject) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Subject') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('math');
        echo $this->Form->input('english');
        echo $this->Form->input('history');
        echo $this->Form->input('science');
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['options' => $users]);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

In your UsersTable(Users Model), add/edit your initialize() as follow

```
$this->displayField('username');
$this->primaryKey('id');
```

Comment: this should work .. even better would be `$users = $this->Subjects->Users->find('list')`, but that would work only if subject and user-model are [associated](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)

Comment: but how will i know if that record i added is belong to that person?  example i choose the user id in this dropdown https://ibb.co/cSDhe5 , then this is the output of the subjects table when i added. please see also the users table on the image   https://ibb.co/nCv9sQ

Comment: I am not sure what you want. Still, you do the following, this will give you drop down with username.
I have added in the above code. @JeromeManatad

Comment: please see the 2 pictures above. if i choose 84 id which is belongs to jovy@gmail.com.. but in the subjects table i cant classify which record belongs to JOVY,

Comment: I have already written the answer, read last 3 line of the above code. Implement that and refresh subject/add @JeromeManatad

Comment: thank you so much bikash.bilz.    for your help, im new and still learning in cakephp. do I need to have fields in subjects table? to insert the name or id added related to users table.... after i choose tyra the output is on the id 3, how to relate that in users table so that i can display the grades of Tyra   https://ibb.co/eLMERk

Comment: wow i added user_id field in subjects table and got the result the id of the  users I assigned  https://ibb.co/krbsWk  ,,, does cakephp automatically insert the data to the new field, what if i change the column to another name?

Comment: Nothing is the new field, you are providing data for the user_id from your form that why CakePHP is adding the data to the table. If you will change the column name in the subject table, then you have to use the same column name in the form field. bikash.neosoft is my skype username, you can add me in your skype @JeromeManatad

Answer (score 0):

1. at your **Controller**

   `$allUser = $this->Users->find(); // this will be get all user from user table
   $this->set('allUser', $allUser);`
2. at your **View**

   `/**@var array $allUser */// already type of array
       <?= $this->Form->select('all_user', [
           'multiple' => true,
           'value' => $allUser
       ]); ?>`

Comment: Undefined variable: allUser [APP/Template\Subjects\add.ctp, line 19]...  i put your code in  method index in usersController.php , then in the add.ctp view in Subjects

Comment: `$this->Users->find();`
make sure this code working, i not sure about your model.

after that check `$allUser` has Data before using it, u can using debug kit of cake for debug 

`debug($allUser); exit;` this code will be print $allUser variable and show it on screen ...

Comment: so you need `debug($allUser->toArray())`---> it will be show for you data 
---
contact me if you need more support

Answer (score -1):

Use $this->Form->select() or $this->Form->input('users', ['options' => array()]);

if you do not want to do foreach loop.

try:

```
<?= $this->Form->select('users', $users); ?>
```

Comment: it says undefined also