# how to display all email and username in users table related with id

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

this question is the continuation of this  [how to display all the users in table users to my subjects table in add.ctp view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830056/how-to-display-all-the-users-in-table-users-to-my-subjects-table-in-add-ctp-view/45834268)

I want to print all the username and email in users table by relating the user_id to the users table  see image below

https://ibb.co/dX8ynQ

I have 2 tables in the picture the users and subjects table. In the subjects table their is user_id that connect to the users table data.

Comment: Did you define relations ?? Please share the code you have tried

Comment: NOPE i dont know how to use relations, im new in cakephp this is my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830056/how-to-display-all-the-users-in-table-users-to-my-subjects-table-in-add-ctp-view/45834268

Comment: If you're brand new to CakePHP, you should go through the tutorial. Relations are a really basic concept, well covered there and in the manual. What you want to do is really trivial once you have relations set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that in SQL

```
SELECT subjects.*,users.username, users.email
FROM subjects
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = subjects.user_id
```

In CakePhP

you can build 2 models ( User and Subject  )

On Subject Model / in initialize make it belongsTo User, pleaser refer to
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Then you can retrieve subject associated to users. please refer to 
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data

```
$query = $subjects->find('all', ['contain' => ['User']]);
```

Comment: your sql query reall answer my questions  https://ibb.co/iehkZ5  ... but im still learning on table relations. do you have sample code with the same scenario.

Comment: $subjects=$this->Subjects->find('all', ['contain'=>['Users'], 'fields'=>['Users.username', 'Users.email']])->hydrate(false)->toArray(); $this->set('subjects', $subjects); how can print the data in the view? I cant just do like this one <?php foreach ($subjects as $subject): ?> <?= h($subject->username) ?> <?= h($subject->email) ?> <?php endforeach; ?>        @PeterTanath